# "iterate" a single object or the index equivalent of a php object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I can get where I'm going, but I want the prettiest road.

What led me here was researching the best way to run a function that returns a collection of objects like `$dom->getElementsByTagName()` or `$pdo->query('SELECT itcher FROM scratches')`and then - knowing that it will only have one result - accessing that result.

I've done some research but I'd like to know that I know all that there is to know.

`foreach` or anything that iterates over multiple *things* felt silly from an aesthetic point-of-view because I know there's just one. Casting it to an array feels like a blemish, and I want to get off to my code. The one I like the most so far is `$object->{'0'}` because it's as close to `$object[0]` as I've found, but it doesn't seem to work in every case. Is there something even prettier to look at? For instance, what exactly is `foreach($key as $val)` doing on each iteration when it sets a $key to $val? Can I do that myself?

Maybe I'm not visualizing the idea of an object properly in my mind, but wouldn't it make more sense for `getElementsByTagName` and mysql queries to return *arrays*? Why don't they?

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies but I use doctrine's getSingleResult() and getArrayResult() functions all the time.  What they do with the query is a mystery to me

Comment: Sometimes with databases you don't want to fetch the entire result set into memory at once, and this is required when returning an array. pdo offers it as an option though via `fetchAll()`. An array also requires the calling code wait for all results to be fetched, whereas returning an iterable provides the opportunity for the calling code to start processing sooner. But, I'm of the opinion arrays should have been default and these special-case interfaces should have been the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For instance, what exactly is foreach($key as $val) doing on each iteration when it sets a $key to $val? Can I do that myself?

If it really is an array, you can get the first element with `reset()`.

If it's an `Iterator` (which is used to allow `foreach` access to an object) then you should be able to use `$object->current();`

I've never really looked at the underlying code for `foreach` - however `reset()` and `current()` seem analogous to what `foreach` would 'do' at the start of iteration.

Unfortunately, the two examples you reference are internal classes, and [according to the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) internal classes (classes that are part of the language or an extension) don't follow the same rules:

> Internal (built-in) classes that implement this interface can be used in a foreach construct and do not need to implement IteratorAggregate or Iterator.

That said, any user classes that return objects that can be iterated by `foreach` should be of a `Traversable` type (what `foreach` requires), so I believe `current()` should work the way you want. Note that if the object actually implements `IteratorAggregate` instead of `Iterator`, you'll have to use `getIterator()->current()`.

However it's still possible to do with your two examples - just using methods specific to those returned types. In the case of `getElementsByTagName()`, you can use `getElementsByTagName->item(0)` and in the case of PDO you can use `query()->fetch()`.

Comment: That makes me feel like I have a much better understanding of what's going on. You're saying that each well-written object will generally have its own method of fetching the next relevant item, right? And the reason there's no global PHP method of doing that is because objects have isolated needs and methods of storing data.

Also, thanks a lot for including the DOM and PDO methods of grabbing that data- that's what made it super clear for me.

Comment: @StatycAutomatyc Kind of, it seems like most objects should have a way to get the first item; however, you'll only need to use object specific methods when you're using internal objects. You should be able to leverage the `current()` for any library/userland code (even if there is no method specific to that object).

Comment: As a note- current() doesn't seem to work on getElementsByTagName as it is an undefined method.

Comment: @StatycAutomatyc That's correct, as documented *internal* classes don't **need** to implement `IteratorAggregate` or `Iterator` (userland classes **do**). So you can't count on `current()` or `getIterator()->current()` working on *internal* classes.

Comment: ohhh- sorry, i got it. didn't know what *internal* meant in this context at first. thanks again, man. tremendous.